# lasagne - unexpected keyword error

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I am trying to learn machine learning in Python - and would like to run the lasagne / nolearn packages. I have installed all packages - and am using the script per below (from http://semantive.com/deep-learning-examples/) which gives the following error. Please let me know if anyone has an idea on how to resolve this error.

the script gives an initial error in only one of the lasagne modules:

```
  File "<ipython-input-89-2752ae2387c3>", line 11, in <module>
    from nolearn.lasagne import visualize

ImportError: cannot import name visualize
```

subsequently - there is an error around the pad argument:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-90-7a7b6ee7a652>", line 66, in <module>
    network = net.fit(x_train, y_train)

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne.py", line 138, in fit
    out = self._output_layer = self.initialize_layers()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nolearn\lasagne.py", line 369, in initialize_layers
    layer = layer_factory(layer, **layer_params)

  File "C:\Users\src\lasagne\lasagne\layers\conv.py", line 368, in __init__
    super(Conv2DLayer, self).__init__(incoming, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pad'
```

the code

```
import cPickle as pickle
    import os
    import numpy as np

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.cm as cm
    import lasagne
    from lasagne import layers
    from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
    from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
    from nolearn.lasagne import visualize
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score


    def load_data(path):
        x_train = np.zeros((50000, 3, 32, 32), dtype='uint8')
        y_train = np.zeros((50000,), dtype="uint8")

        for i in range(1, 6):
            data = unpickle(os.path.join(path, 'data_batch_' + str(i)))
            images = data['data'].reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32)
            labels = data['labels']
            x_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000, :, :, :] = images
            y_train[(i - 1) * 10000:i * 10000] = labels

        test_data = unpickle(os.path.join(path, 'test_batch'))
        x_test = test_data['data'].reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32)
        y_test = np.array(test_data['labels'])

        return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test


    def unpickle(file):
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        dict = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        return dict


    net = NeuralNet(
        layers=[('input', layers.InputLayer),
                ('conv2d1', layers.Conv2DLayer),
                ('maxpool1', layers.MaxPool2DLayer),
                ('conv2d2', layers.Conv2DLayer),
                ('maxpool2', layers.MaxPool2DLayer),
                ('dense', layers.DenseLayer),
                ('output', layers.DenseLayer),
                ],
        input_shape=(None, 3, 32, 32),
        conv2d1_num_filters=20,
        conv2d1_filter_size=(5, 5),
        conv2d1_stride=(1, 1),
        conv2d1_pad=(2, 2),
        conv2d1_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
        maxpool1_pool_size=(2, 2),
        conv2d2_num_filters=20,
        conv2d2_filter_size=(5, 5),
        conv2d2_stride=(1, 1),
        conv2d2_pad=(2, 2),
        conv2d2_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
        maxpool2_pool_size=(2, 2),
        dense_num_units=1000,
        dense_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.rectify,
        output_nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax,
        output_num_units=10,
        update=nesterov_momentum,
        update_momentum=0.9,
        update_learning_rate=0.0001,
        max_epochs=100,
        verbose=True
    )

    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_data(os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox/Python/cifar-10-python.tar/cifar-10-python/cifar-10-batches-py/'))

    network = net.fit(x_train, y_train)
    predictions = network.predict(x_test)

    print classification_report(y_test, predictions)
    print accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
```

Comment: Can you tell us on what line in *your* code this happens?

Comment: show us the entire exception trace. The error concerns keyword argument "pad" but your script doesn't create a class with that argument. Its possible that you have incompatible modules installed.  Whatever is calling conv.py has its parameters wrong.

Comment: apologies - find the entire exception trace inserted in the updated post

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using an incompatible version of Lasagne for your nolearn version.

The `pad` feature was added to the `Conv2DLayer` class in Lasagne in July and August 2015 (see [here](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/commit/7a6c9e59c547efaf1a34484ae587f96b03797993) and [here](https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/commit/6d18347bdb52b1c7f71ae1802ed6a6a418eb8ea1)). Your version of nolearn clearly expects to be using that version or later.

There are two possibilities:

1. You (presumably accidentally) have two versions of Lasagne on your system but its an older one that's found first by Python. If this is true, remove the older version and/or make sure the newer version is found (first) by Python.
2. You simply have an outdated version of Lasagne. Solution: update it! How you do that may depend on how you installed it in the first place. Ultimately you'll need to get the latest version from Github though.